# Specify custom datapoint in Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Is there anyway (or plugin) to specify a custom label for each data point in flot?  Ideally, for the hoverover for each data point I would like to display the following:

`y = 56% for South Center`

Where y is the yaxis datapoint, and 'South Center' is the custom label for the datapoint.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Flot you bind a function to the plothover event.  That function can display anything you want.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/YuDzw/1/).